# Cannot use (type interface{}) as type []Type

Tags: go, casting, slice

I have this code:

```
  requestHistory := claims["request_history"]

  if requestHistory == nil {
     requestHistory = []float64{}
  }

  requestHistory, ok = requestHistory.([]float64)

  if !ok {
    return getBytes(http.StatusForbidden, cptypes.ErrorResponseData{
      ErrId:  "7d700df9-6cc9-447c-a8ce-37701fd71a8c",
      Reason: "missing created_at value in jwt claims.",
    })
  }

  requestHistory = append(requestHistory, float64(time.Now().Unix()))  // error here!

  if len(requestHistory) > 25 {   // error here too!
      //
  }
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error:

> Cannot use 'requestHistory' (type interface{}) as type []Type

and

> Invalid argument for len

it appears strongly that this re-assignment:

```
 requestHistory, ok = requestHistory.([]float64)
```

is not actually in scope below it? very strange golang thing going on here

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: You're doing the assertion but storing the result back into requestHistory, which is `interface{}`. Get a new variable (and give it the correct type). E.g. if you did `floatslice, ok := requestHistory.([]float64)` you could then use`floatslice` with `append` and `len` and `range` and whatever else that can be used with slice types.

Comment: `interface{}` does **not** mean "any type". It means just `interface{}`.

Comment: please the check value of the requestHistory before appending as there might be invalid append you are trying to achieve or the other issue is that you are trying to append to wrong variable type .Please check the type of each variable and also check wither they are pointer reference or not and then try append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is some weird golang thing:

```
  requestHistory := claims["request_history"]    // 1

  if requestHistory == nil {
     requestHistory = []float64{}
  }

  requestHistory, ok = requestHistory.([]float64)   // 2
```

the line labeled // 2 does not reassign the variable to a new type, it maintains the original type of `interface{}` which is declared from line // 1

Ultimately this is why programming error, the right way to do this is to start here instead:

```
requestHistory, ok := claims["request_history"].([]interface{})
```

where `claims` is type `map[string]interface{}`